# recombine split TCP packet with flash sockets

Tags: c++, flash, actionscript-3, sockets

I have a program in c++ that sends a socket of 23723 bytes to a flash player in one "shot".

The flash player sometimes receives two packets of size 17520 and 6203, and other times it receives a single packet of 23723.

EDIT: There does not seem to be a way to obtain the total number of bytes associated with the send data from flash. This would make it very difficult to build a loop to reconstruct the "broken" packet.

I thought TCP was supposed to correctly recombine the packets and I am having difficulty recombining them myself.

This is my receiving handler in flash:

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket();
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnectHandler);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataReceivedHandler);
socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 7445);
socket.writeUTFBytes("hi");

private function socketDataReceivedHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
  var socket:Socket = event.target as Socket;
  trace(socket.bytesAvailable);
  var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
  socket.readBytes(data);
}
```

The command:

```
trace(socket.bytesAvailable);
```

will at times print 23723, and at other times, will print 17520 quickly followed by 6203. The total size are just examples and are subject to change for each send sockets. Also many sockets can be sent or received at the same time, so the split packets can be inter-mixed. In c++ I could determine what the total size of the sent data was, even if I did not receive the whole sent data yet.

Comment: No - TCP does not deal with packets. It gives you just a stream of bytes. You should e.g. write the size of the data first, so your reading end knows how much data to read. Or if you always send a fixed number of bytes, have your reading end loop until it read all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with tcp. The socket can send you any number of bytes as long as it is at least one byte. So you might get [1, 23722]. The correct way to do this is to call read in a loop and fill an array yourself. If your code does not contain a loop but works, then it works by accident. This cannot work without a loop.

Edit: do not use bytesAvailable. Check the return value of the read function. Check your code: If your code relies on bytesAvailable it is wrong.

Edit2: Looks like the flash api (which I do not know) works differently from the socket api that all other frameworks and languages use. I assumed it would work the same, so let me correct: You are supposed to have the following loop:

```
int writePos = 0;
var array = ...;
while true:
 wait for bytes to become available. i do not know how to do this but one method would be 'while bytesAvailable == 0 then sleep 10'
 var bytesAvailableCopy = bytesAvailable; //copy because this value can change anytime
 socket.read(array, writePos, bytesAvailableCopy );
 writePos += bytesAvailableCopy;
 if(writePos == maxLength) break;
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I do the loop? The problem is that in c++, the socket object will tell me how many bytes I am supposed to get. Then I can loop until the buffer equals the number of bytes I should receive. However, in Flash there does not appear to be a way to obtain the number of bytes I should get. I thought the availability of the number of expected bytes was part of TCP.

Comment: Added code. Notice the loop only terminates when all bytes have been consumed. It can work with any number of chunks.

Comment: A TCP socket is simply passing a stream of bytes through.  It's up to your application to add a protocol or layer on top that splits the stream into meaningful packets.  TCP does guarantee the data will arrive in the correct order.

Comment: In response with you edit: Tcp does not provide this service. It does not tell you how many bytes the other endpoint will send - it cannot because it does not know. Your client must send as the first 4 bytes of its message the total message length (only an example). http does this with the content-length http header. Without the header browsers could never tell if they received everything.

Comment: "In c++ I could determine what the total size of the sent data was, even if I did not receive the whole sent data yet." This cannot be true.

Comment: The old fashion way was to always put the packet size as the first 4 (or whatever) bytes of the packet.  Then you read the packet size, and you know how many bytes to loop for.  Would that work for you?

Comment: @Trevor -- Actually I think that TCP/IP *does* guarantee the data arrives in the right order.  You're thinking of UDP/IP.

Comment: Ok. I will add a "message-size" header to my packet. By I am not sure about this: Do I have to also use a GUID to id my packet, so that I do not combine two unrelated packets by mistake?

Comment: @Michale J - I think you misread my comment.  I said TCP does guarantee the data will arrive in the correct order.  You are correct, though.  UDP will not guarantee delivery or correct sequencing of packets.  UDP does not have the problem TCP has of knowing how large each packet needs to be though.  The size is built into the UDP datagram.

Comment: @ Alexandre H. Tremblay, you don't have to have a guid. The stream of bytes is contiguous. You still don't have the right understanding yet because if you had your question would not make sense to you. If tcp did not guarantee that "messages" don't intermix tcp would not guarantee that the guid itself would arrive in a single chunk either. There is no message concept with tcp. It is like a file with a size you don't know until the socket closes.

Comment: Ah now I know how to explain! Reading from tcp is like reading from an IEnumerable<byte[]>: you get chunks of arbitrary size (greter than zero) and you don't know in advance how many you will get.

Comment: @Trevor - You are correct.  I did misread your comment.  My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Okay... try and understand this. TCP Sockets isn't about transferring packets over the network (at least conceptually), its actually a stream of bytes which are transferred in the same sequence to be received on the other end, without fail.

Now the lower layers (IP and so on), breaks the stream into packets and send it over the network. The TCP stack on the receiving end reassembles the packets (ask for retransmissions if necessary) and form a stream out of it again, as and when it keeps receiving the packets from lower layers. A `read()` socket call on the destination will fetch you the bytes that are received in the stream so far. Therefore, you can never be sure if a single `read()` call will fetch you all the data that was sent.

The trick is to use multiple `read()` calls. You can have two possible scenarios to deal with this:

(1) When you know how exactly many bytes you're supposed to receive. Here, you just keep on calling `read()` until you have received the said amount of bytes.

(2) When you don't know how many bytes you're supposed to receive. This is rather tricky. Here you have to decide on a Sentinel. So, at the sending end, you send all the data that you have to send and then send this Sentinel. By the time I'm sure you must have understood it that at the receiving end, you keep on `read()`ing until you receive the Sentinel.

Never think of TCP-Sockets as packets. Its easy to sink it in when you think of them as streams.